# Return optional from class method

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I have a optional member in a class, which I want to return by value, via a method.
Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class bar {
public:
    int a;

    bar(const bar &obj) {
        a = obj.a;
    }
};

class foo {
public:
    void init(){
        abc->a = 100;
    }

    optional<bar> get() {
        return abc;
    }
    
    optional<bar> abc;
};

int main()
{
    foo temp;
    temp.init();
    auto copied = temp.get();
    cout << "Expected value is 100, got: " << copied->a;
    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs some garbage value.

How may I achieve this?

---

From my understanding, optional stores a fully allocated memory for the underlying type (not just a reference), and while returning a optional variable, the copy constructor of the underlying type should kick in, which should copy the memory as-is to the new optional value being returned.

Comment: The default constructor of `std::optional` creates an *empty* optional (contains no value), so your `foo` constructor `abc->a = 100;` invokes *undefined behavior* (as you have no object to access)

Comment: What matters is whether an object exists inside the memory or not; that there’s room for one isn’t enough.

Comment: @UnholySheep How to add assign a value to the optional? `member_.value() = newValue`?

Comment: @UnholySheep @molbdnilo I updated the sample code to initialize the underlying type via a separate `init` call and invoked the `init` api in the main function. Now, the underlying type should be initialized properly to be copied over, right?

Comment: No, `value()` throws an exception if the optional does not contain a value. You either construct the optional with a value (using the corresponding constructor overload) or you use the overloaded `operator=`, or the member function `emplace` (if you want to create the object in-place)

Comment: The `bar` class is not instantiable as is, since the only constructor it provides is a copy constructor. You should add at least a default constructor or a converting constructor from `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the constructor of `optional` to ensure that it contains an object: (assuming that the redundant copy constructor of `bar`, which blocks it from being constructed, is removed)

```
foo()
    : abc{bar{100}}
{
}
```

or, after the `optional` has been created:

```
void init(){
    abc = bar{100};
}
```

Otherwise, the `optional` is kept in an empty state, and invoking `->` on an empty `optional` results in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*).  The copy constructor of `optional` does not copy construct a contained object when the source is empty.

Comment: I made some edits to my question. Basically I cannot initialize the optional member in the constructor, so I added an init method to do that. How would that change this answer?

Comment: @Nishant use assignment instead.  `emplace` works too. See update.

Comment: Note that `bar` would need to have a suitable converting constructor to make this work.

Comment: @L.F. I do need a default constructor for bar, does not work otherwise.

Comment: @Nishant Oops, overlooked that.  Right now there is no (legit) way to construct an object of type `bar`, as far as I can tell, so `optional` won't help you with that.

Comment: @DanielLangr indeed, I neglected that.  `bar` can't be used as-is anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional` is like a smart pointer, it defaults to a "null" value and accessing its members would therefore be undefined behaviour. You need to initialise it before use:

```
void init(){
  abc = bar();
  abc->a = 100;
}
```

Note that as it stands `bar` isn't constructible other than via the copy constructor so you need to add a default constructor or a constructor that takes an `int` argument or remove the unnecessary copy constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I made these changes to the question. Still I do not see the value being copied over. Here is sample run: https://onlinegdb.com/Hk5F9IDEv

Comment: `bar` needs to have a default constructor for this.

Comment: @Nishant works with my change (and the addition of a constructor for `bar`): https://onlinegdb.com/ryI7iLPEv